# Python: Modified Bubble Sort

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

This program is written in python. It's goal is to move ONE out of place number to its proper place through swaps, then to output the number of swaps it took. So it's very similar to bubble sort except the program doesn't have to switch with a number adjacent to it. See an example below

Sample input:

```
5 2 4 7 7 3
```

Sample output:  2

Sample explanation:
24773 - starting set of 5 integers
24377 - swap the 3 for the first 7 (first swap) (the 7 is not next to the 3)
23477 - swap the 3 and 4 to get the number least to greatest (second swap)

Here is my current code in Python. It does the traditional bubble sort method.

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
times = 0
for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
            times = times + 1 
            temp = alist[i]
            alist[i] = alist[i+1]
            alist[i+1] = temp
            print(alist)

return(times)

arrin = [5, 2, 4, 7, 7, 3]
print(bubbleSort(arrin))
```

This outputs: `3`
This answer is incorrect because the bubble sort swapped the 3 with the adjacent 7, increasing the output to 3 (should be 2).

How would I modify this code to satisfy the example?

Comment: thanks for the heads up @srig. Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating map in which key is the value of array and value is the index of array. After that, loop through input list, and compare current value and value from sorted list. If it is different:
-increment the number of swaps
-get index of the sorted list from map, map[sorted list]
-in input list swap current value with sorted current value
update map[current list value]=map[sorted current list value]
This needs to be executed on input list and reversed input list. Whichever is smaller is the answer.

```
def bubbleSort(alist):

 m = {}
 for i in range(len(alist)):
     m[alist[i]] = i 

 sorted_alist = sorted(alist)
 times = 0

 for i in range(len(alist)):
     if alist[i] != sorted_alist[i]:
         times +=1
         ind_to_swap = m[ sorted_alist[i] ]
         m[ alist[i] ] = m[ sorted_alist[i]]
         alist[i],alist[ind_to_swap] = sorted_alist[i],alist[i]
 return times

arrin = [2, 4, 7, 7, 3]
asc=bubbleSort(arrin)
desc=bubbleSort(list(reversed(arrin)))
print (min(asc,desc))
```